# Shouldn't an element that has position: relative be a part of the normal document flow?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a component, which has a div with `position: relative` and a div nested inside that with `position: absolute`. When I introduce the element into my other component, they overlap.

Here's the first component:

```
<div className={classes.positionRelative}>
    <div className={classes.absoluteList}>
        <div className={classes.flexWrapper}>
            <img
                className={classes.coinImg}
                src={currentCoin}
                alt='current coin'
            />
            <input
                className={inputSizeDecider}
                onChange={storeInputText}
            />
            <img src={search} alt='search icon' />
        </div>
        {inputText != '' && (
            <ul>
                {coins &&
                    coins
                        .filter(coin => {
                            if (
                                coin.name
                                    .slice(0, inputText.length)
                                    .toLowerCase() ==
                                inputText.toLowerCase()
                            ) {
                                return coin;
                            }
                        })
                        .map((coin, i) => (
                            <div key={`div${i}`}>
                                <img
                                    src={coin.image}
                                    alt='coin logo'
                                    key={`img${i}`}
                                />
                                <p key={`p${i}`}>{coin.name}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))}
            </ul>
        )}
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.positionRelative {
    position: relative;
}

.absoluteList {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: top;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.flexWrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flexWrapper > input {
    width: 20vw;
    padding-left: 2vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.coinImg {
    height: 2.5vh;
}
```

second component (no css)

```
<div>
    <Searchbar />
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio
        adipisci facilis sapiente incidunt laboriosam provident esse
        eius ut, odio doloremque magni! Earum voluptates distinctio qui
        sint temporibus assumenda nobis vero.
    </p>
</div>
```

The Searchbar component, and the paragraph are just stacked on top of eachother when I run this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.positionRelative` element doesn't have any other child elements except `.absoluteList` – which has `position:absolute`.

But elements that have `position:absolute` *don't take any space of their own*! So your `.positionRelative` is rendered like an element without content, and therefore is has zero height. (Use the browser tools to inspect that, then you'll see it). And therefore its absoluteley positioned child will overlap *other* elements in the document flow.

So in order to create space for `.absoluteList`, you have to define a manual `height` for your `.positionRelative` element.

Or instead, consider to erase `position:absolute` from `.absoluteList`, so it is treated as regular content of `.positionRelative`.